# When using LESS, are there any disadvantages to using multiple mixins rather than multiple selectors?

Tags: html, css, performance, less

From a page speed / performance perspective, which method is better?

Example:

```
<a class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">
```

Would it be preferable to create a new class using several mixins?

```
<a class="btn-home">

.btn-home {
    .btn;
    .btn-success;
    .btn-lg;
    .btn-block;
}
```

It seems like this is better form a DRY perspective and might have performance benefits.

From a page speed / performance perspective multiple selectors can be slow by forcing the browser to do more work. Is there any improvement to the page speed to make this happen using LESS?

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't a definitive answer to this, it solely depends on the style of your workflow, your specific needs etc. This isn't a good question for this site.

Comment: Performance in what aspect? CSS rendering? LESS compilation?

Comment: What are you comparing it to? You only got one sample there

Comment: Strictly speaking, in many cases, these four ruleset calls do not necessarily create a style being *equal* to `class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block"` - for more details see [this collection of links](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/cefc873a78fa12924462).